# Flex with a static width container

Tags: css, flexbox

**ISSUE:**
When I assign a static width to the flex'a parent container, the flex functionality stops working.

**MY GOAL:**
To have a functional flex layout within a parent container that has a static width.

**RIGHT NOW:**
This flex layout works perfectly using a "100%" parent container width.  But the "flex" stops working when I assign a static width.

**Meaning...**
As long as the current 100% width equals the window size, the flex functions correctly ... as it adjusts to the window's width.

**More info:**

- This flex code will be used within a themed page that only allows for HTML & JS/JQ.
- This section will be within a "middle" section of the template/page.
- I'm not using a CMS (i.e.: Wordpress)
- The template's CSS has the "page" class as 100% width... something that I cannot change
- The flex section needs to be centered horizontally in the page

**JSFiddle:**
The default CSS in the JSFiddle below is using the "100%" width for the container = Flex works fine.  I have commented the CSS class parameter (mainwrapper) that causes the flex to stop working.

`JSFiddle Link:`**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bobbielee17/u1s9jrsd/)**

Comment: check my answer i think it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max-width:980px` you can remove `width:100%` because i assigned maximum width `980px`.

If i missed some thing please check fiddle code

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1s9jrsd/8/)**

```
.mainwrapper {
  width: 100%;
  /* Here's the problem:*/
  /* Asigning a static width breaks flex */
  max-width: 980px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
.page {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainwrapper {
  width: 100%;
  /* Here's the problem:*/
  /* Asigning a static width breaks flex */
  max-width: 980px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Product Layout */

.section-holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.section-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2%;
  flex: 1 24%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.section-image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.section-info {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media ( max-width: 768px) {
  .section-item {
    flex: 1 21%;
  }
  .section-holder .section-item {
    flex: 2 46%;
  }
}

@media ( max-width: 680px) {
  .section-item {
    flex: 1 46%;
  }
}

@media ( max-width: 480px) {
  .section-item {
    flex: 1 100%;
  }
  .section-holder .section-item {
    flex: 2 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div align="center" class="page">
  <div class="mainwrapper">

    <div class="section-holder">
      <div class="section-item">
        <div class="section-image">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0938/8938/products/10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1445623369">
        </div>
        <div class="section-info">
          <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
          <h6>$99.99</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section-item">
        <div class="section-image">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0938/8938/products/10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1445623369">
        </div>
        <div class="section-info">
          <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
          <h6>$99.99</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section-item">
        <div class="section-image">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0938/8938/products/10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1445623369">
        </div>
        <div class="section-info">
          <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
          <h6>$99.99</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section-item">
        <div class="section-image">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0938/8938/products/10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1445623369">
        </div>
        <div class="section-info">
          <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
          <h6>$99.99</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section-item">
        <div class="section-image">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0938/8938/products/10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1445623369">
        </div>
        <div class="section-info">
          <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
          <h6>$99.99</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section-item">
        <div class="section-image">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0938/8938/products/10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1445623369">
        </div>
        <div class="section-info">
          <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
          <h6>$99.99</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section-item">
        <div class="section-image">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0938/8938/products/10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1445623369">
        </div>
        <div class="section-info">
          <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
          <h6>$99.99</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section-item">
        <div class="section-image">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0938/8938/products/10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1445623369">
        </div>
        <div class="section-info">
          <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
          <h6>$99.99</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section-item">
        <div class="section-image">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0938/8938/products/10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1445623369">
        </div>
        <div class="section-info">
          <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
          <h6>$99.99</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section-item">
        <div class="section-image">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0938/8938/products/10231100205_1_1315x1800_300_CMYK_1024x1024.jpeg?v=1445623369">
        </div>
        <div class="section-info">
          <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
          <h6>$99.99</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the `display` for the class `page` to `flex` from `block`. If I am understanding your question correctly.

```
.page {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

to

```
.page {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that the template's CSS has the "page" class as 100% width... something that I cannot change.  And.. the flex section needs to be centered horizontally in the page. (*I updated my "More Info" section)

Comment: Could it be that as long as the parent container is a static value, there is nothing to "flex"?  Therefore, the only way to simulate a flex is to use media queries?

Comment: @mar2195 instead of `text-align: center;` if you add `margin: 0 auto` it centered the content.

`
.mainwrapper {
      width: 300px;
      margin: 0 auto;
}
`